# Float <span> on right and the rest(text) on left, within <div> in ie 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

I have some text and `<span>` tag, which are inside a `<div>`.

`<span>` is `float: right;` I need the text to be on the left side and `<span>` on right side.

In every browser it displays perfectly except `ie7`. How can I fix this bug?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Testing page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="border:2px solid #000; display:inline;"> 
            welcome<span style="float:right"> demo</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your problem is really IE7, but I guess you can't fix that... ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

move span before text, this should help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, its working .. but now i can't interchange that, because its in the production process. 
Above i shown you a sample data. 

Is there any other solution to solve my issue ?

Comment: Thank you i fixed the bug using this way itself. Because all the other ways which i got was complicated than your way(i think so).

Comment: Could you explain why? I will up vote if you elaborate your answer.

Comment: thats really simple and effective.

Answer (score 8):

Make *span* as block element and move it.

I.e.

```
span{
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Would it be possible to enclose the text in a `<p>` and have that `display: inline`?

Comment: Thank you... But i think its better to go with @simoncereska's way.
I fixed the bug using that method.

Answer (score 0):

User the following css it will work. **[DEMO LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/En83R/1/)**

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }
body {
    font:normal 12px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    padding:20px;
    }
.container {
    border:2px solid #000;
    padding:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
    }
.container span {
    display:inline-block;
    *float:left;
    }
```